# Android app Crashes when accessing a button

Tags: android, android-button

I am building an App in which, whenever i access a button like 
`Button btn1= (Button)findViewById(R.id._id);`
 When i am putting this piece of code inside my project and
run my project, it crashes my app, But when i //comment this line and then run everything fine. I don't know what's the problem! 
below is My xml code:

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="430dp"
    android:id="@+id/WebField"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnFB" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnNYT" />
```

My Java Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   Button buttonNYT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNYT); // this line has
    WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebField);
```

Comment: Use `ImageButton` instead of `Button`

Comment: Also, please post the exception. You can see it in the Android logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **ImageButton** Instead of **Button** eg.

```
ImageButton buttonNYT = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNYT);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use ImageButton. ImageButton is not related to Button and you cannot cast it.

```
   ImageButton buttonNYT = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNYT); // this line has
```

Thanks
Sriram